# Take CellEditing plugin from editor listeners

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the grid with cell editing. When someone press enter in the celleditor - extjs need to open editor in next row and same cell. 
I know, that this action does **startEdit()** method of CellEditing class. But how can I access CellEditing of that grid from listener of CellEditor.

```
listeners:{
    specialkey: function(field, e){
        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('sheetproductionrestin');
            var store = Ext.getCmp('sheetproductionrestin').store;
            var selModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
            var selectedRecord = selModel.getLastSelected();

            var recordIndex = store.indexOf(selectedRecord);
            var nextRecord = store.getAt(recordIndex + 1);
            selModel.select(nextRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

This code makes next row focused, but how can I access Editing Plugin and call StartEdit from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access plugin via [`getPlugin` method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getPlugin) provided you have assigned pluginId to your plugin:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 2,
        pluginId: 'cellplugin'
    })],
    columns: [
        {
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            listeners: {
                specialkey: function(field, e) {
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                        var grid = Ext.getCmp('sheetproductionrestin');
                        var store = Ext.getCmp('sheetproductionrestin').store;
                        var selModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
                        var selectedRecord = selModel.getLastSelected();

                        var recordIndex = store.indexOf(selectedRecord);
                        var nextRecord = store.getAt(recordIndex + 1);
                        selModel.select(nextRecord);

                        var plugin = grid.getPlugin('cellplugin');
                        plugin.startEdit(nextRecord, grid.columns[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }},
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/b2XTL/) (the first column is editable).

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do the opposite? Inside a listener of the cellplugin to get a reference to the actual field that is being created on the fly for editing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do is just store a reference to the cell editing plugin like this:

```
myGrid.cellEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing');
```

Then you can assign it to the grid like this:

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    plugins: [myGrid.cellEditor]
```

Then when you need to start the edit you can call `myGrid.cellEditor.startEdit(colNumber)`